# How "head & shoulders" sounds for native english speakers?

Tags: meaning

Translating "Head & Shoulders" (the shampoo brand) in my mother tongue (Bulgarian) it sounds really dumb.

But is it sounds dumb for native english language speakers as well? 
Or it sounds some kind of more reasonable?

[image]

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=head+and+shoulders&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chead%20and%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Can you give the context, please?  "Head and shoulders" is an idiom in English, and it's also a trademark for a brand of shampoo.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you intend to use it? "This tastes head & shoulders" does not sound reasonable, but "The protective hood covered her head and shoulders while she worked in the laboratory" sounds fine.

Comment: It is also the name of a pattern that shows up in charts of stocks, and if you own the stock it's not a pattern you want to see.

Comment: I am talking about the shamboo brand. (probably need to edit the question) I didn't know about the idiom. What it means? This way, if there is an idiom, this can change the whole understanding of this phrase.

Comment: The Blondie song "[Look Good in Blue](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/blondie/lookgoodinblue.html)" turns the phrase (without *above*) into a [double entendre](https://www.google.com/search?q=double+entendre) with the lyrics *If it's alright with you, I could give you some head and shoulders to lie on*. *To give/get (some) head* refers to a certain sexual act.

Comment: I live in the U.S.  When I hear "Head and Shoulders,"  I think, dandruff shampoo.  No more and no less.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that we use the phrase *head and shoulders*. The shampoo is specifically an anti-dandruff shampoo. Its name is a reference to the fact that if dandruff is really bad, dandruff flakes (bits of dead skin from the scalp) can fall off one's *head* and show up on one's *shoulders*. (As I see John Feltz just answered while I was typing this.)

However, it is also a play on the common idiom **head and shoulders above (the rest)**. From Cambridge Dictionaries:

> [**head and shoulders above**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/head-and-shoulders-above)
>
> If someone or something is head and shoulders above other people or things, he, she, or it is a lot better
> than them:
> *There's no competition - they're head and shoulders above
> the rest.*

The origin of this is literal: picture a crowd of people, with one person who is so tall that his or her head and shoulders are higher than the tops of everyone else's heads. Like an adult with a bunch of 8-year-olds or a professional basketball player among ordinary-height adults.

So the shampoo's name is a fairly clever play on how much better it (supposedly) is at preventing dandruff than its competitors. I don't know that there would be a good way to translate this if the idiom isn't common in your language.

Comment: I know what dandruff is. I asked about the subjective perception of this phrase for the native speakers. But the idiom explains it completely.

Comment: @johnfound I figured you probably did, but the question doesn't specifically mention or define dandruff, and I generally try to write answers that will make sense to other readers who might not have the same background as the original asker. Glad the explanation of the idiom helped!

Answer (score 3):

One normally doesn't translate brand names.

The brand "Head & Shoulders(TM)" was originally conceived and marketed specifically as an anti-dandruff shampoo. [Dandruff](https://www.aad.org/public/skin-hair-nails/hair-care/how-to-treat-dandruff) is a disorder that causes dry, flaky skin on the scalp - as the flakes fall off, they may rest on your shoulders and be very visible against dark-colored clothing.

Therefore the name implies "no dandruff flakes on your clothes because the dandruff itself has been cured".

The appropriate way to translate "Head & Shoulders(TM)" is to give the literal name, with a parenthetical explanation of what it's for.  (Unless the manufacturor, Proctor & Gamble, has a translation or transliteration for the Bulgarian market.)

Comment: As a curiosity, in Portugal they maintained the original English name, which most Portuguese didn't understand at all. A couple of years ago, they've finally adjusted it: now it's H&S. In the very least, easier for non-English speakers to remember.

Answer (score -2):

The phrase kind of makes me think of the song, which is usually sung to/with little kids.

I don't think that I've ever heard "head and shoulders" used in conversation (unless you are describing somebody's head and their shoulders for some reason), so it might sound a little out of place.  There's a brand of shampoo called "Head & Shoulders" though.

Comment: Well, I am talking exactly about the shampoo brand.

Comment: I've never heard someone described as "knees and toes above the rest of the class".

Comment: @HotLicks Duly noted.  I'm not really sure what the point is though.

Comment: The point is that the idiom is "head and shoulders above", not simply "head and shoulders".

Comment: @HotLicks That really has nothing to do with any discussion on this page, especially after the OP edited his question to make it clear that he was talking about the shampoo...

Comment: But the shampoo name obviously came from the idiom.

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe it did.  It's pretty much irrelevant though.

Comment: The idiom is why the name does not seem "dumb" to native AmE speakers.

Comment: (As it is, your "answer" does not answer the question.)

Comment: @HotLicks OP asked for peoples' opinions.  You're not the executive neuron of English speaking Americans...